# Group data by each hour using admit and discharge times in a visit-level dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with patient visit-level data (each row is a unique individual's hospital visit). There is a column for `admit_timestamp` and another for `discharge_timestamp`. I need to calculate several metrics (e.g., total patients per hour) for each hour in a day (0-23). The final result would be a (24 x `C`) matrix, where each row is an hour, and `C` depends on the aggregated metrics I end up calculating. Note that this is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180558/how-to-group-data-by-each-two-3-7-hours-groups-in-pandas) because I can't simply use `pd.resample` on one column---I have to account for the entire span of time a patient is in the hospital, which may be more than 1 day. I'm trying to find an efficient implementation, since it's an operation that will occur on a few GBs worth of data every few weeks (in batch). I'm hoping this community can point me in the right direction. Consider the following reproducible example:

Say, we had 3 patients, with admit/discharge timestamps as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'patient_id':[1,2,3],
    'admit_timestamp':['2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 22:00:00'],
    'discharge_timestamp':['2021-01-01 02:00:00', '2021-01-02 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 23:30:00']
})

df.admit_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.admit_timestamp)
df.discharge_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.discharge_timestamp)
```

If I wanted to simply calculate the total number of patients per hour (the easiest of the metrics I need), I would expect a table like this:

```
Hour | Count
0      2
1      2
2      1
.      .
.      .
.      .
23     1.5
```

I started to play around with combining `pd.interval_range` to create a list of relevant hours, with `pd.explode` to melt the data so that each row represents a unique patient-hour, but not sure whether this is an optimal approach.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: You mention that patients could be present for more than 1 day, can you please clarify how you handle that in your counting?  Also, you list "1.5" total in hour 23, which is the sum on 1 + 0.5 for two patients... you want to count total hours as a float on admission and discharges that don't occur on the hour? Or are you trying to count if they were present at any point during the hour?  A few more examples in your dataframe would help.